# Php using fetch() to get value

Tags: php, android, json

I wish to get data from my DB and insert it into an array to pass it to my android application. Data to be fetched:

> The cottages are all pre-fabricated structures in-line with the strict norms of Ecotourism so as to retain the original character and ruggedness of the forest cover. As the car stops, you’ll find yourself on a gentle hill slope, under a thick cover of oak and pine trees. Welcome to Aamod at Shoghi, the finest resort of Shimla.
>   Another of our best kept secrets at Aamod Shoghi is our bakery. The aroma of freshly baked goodies will entice you every waking hour. We won’t be surprised if you ask us to pack a few assortments to carry back home. We claim to be the best bakers in all of Shimla restaurants.
>   A day at Aamod is never without action. Open your windows early morning for a majestic view and fresh air. And with this begins your day full of surprises. Have team breakfast in our sprawling lawns or play interesting team building games with the help of our multitude of facilities. You can have Business retreats in our spacious conference rooms. While your team is busy at team building activities you can plan your next leadership retreat over a game of golf on our professionally maintained chipping and putting greens!

But script crashes everytime.

```
$resort_name = $_POST['resort_name'];

$sql = "SELECT resort_desc from resorts where resort_name = :resort_name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':resort_name', $resort_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount()){
    $response["resort_desc"] = array();
    $response["resort_desc"][0] = $stmt->fetch();
    $response["success"] = 1;
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
}
```

Is the size of the result too much? If so how can I get this data?

var_dump('response')
      `

```
array(1) {
   array(2) {
     ["resort_desc"]=>
  string(1135) "The cottages are all pre-fabricated structures in-line with the strict norms of Ecotourism so as to retain the original character and ruggedness of the forest cover. As the car stops, you�ll find yourself on a gentle hill slope, under a thick cover of oak and pine trees. Welcome to Aamod at Shoghi, the finest resort of Shimla. Another of our best kept secrets at Aamod Shoghi is our bakery. The aroma of freshly baked goodies will entice you every waking hour. We won�t be surprised if you ask us to pack a few assortments to carry back home. We claim to be the best bakers in all of Shimla restaurants. A day at Aamod is never without action. Open your windows early morning for a majestic view and fresh air. And with this begins your day full of surprises. Have team breakfast in our sprawling lawns or play interesting team building games with the help of our multitude of facilities. You can have Business retreats in our spacious conference rooms. While your team is busy at team building activities you can plan your next leadership retreat over a game of golf on our professionally maintained chipping and putting greens!"

  string(1135) "The cottages are all pre-fabricated structures in-line with the strict norms of Ecotourism so as to retain the original character and ruggedness of the forest cover. As the car stops, you�ll find yourself on a gentle hill slope, under a thick cover of oak and pine trees. Welcome to Aamod at Shoghi, the finest resort of Shimla. Another of our best kept secrets at Aamod Shoghi is our bakery. The aroma of freshly baked goodies will entice you every waking hour. We won�t be surprised if you ask us to pack a few assortments to carry back home. We claim to be the best bakers in all of Shimla restaurants. A day at Aamod is never without action. Open your windows early morning for a majestic view and fresh air. And with this begins your day full of surprises. Have team breakfast in our sprawling lawns or play interesting team building games with the help of our multitude of facilities. You can have Business retreats in our spacious conference rooms. While your team is busy at team building activities you can plan your next leadership retreat over a game of golf on our professionally maintained chipping and putting greens!"
   }
 }
["success"]=>
int(1)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Whether any errors are displayed?

Comment: There is no data passed back. I checked on Postman. Using var_dump($_POST) I can see that the data has passed but there is no echo back. @Anton

Comment: In this script how you are passing the data to the Android app..?

Comment: How is $response printing? Can you copy `var_dump($response);` output?

Comment: This is how I am passing it 'echo json_encode($response)'. var_dump($response) posted in the question @Anton